# Why and when should one call _fpreset( )?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, floating-point

The only documentation I can find (on MSDN or otherwise) is that a call to `_fpreset()` "resets the floating-point package."  What is the "floating point package?"  Does this also clear the FPU status word?  I see documentation that says to call `_fpreset()` when recovering from a SIGFPE, but doesn't `_clearfp()` do this as well?  Do I need to call both?

I am working on an application that unmasks some FP exceptions (using `_controlfp()`).  When I want to reset the FPU to the default state (say, when calling to .NET code), should I just call `_clearfp()`, `_fpreset()`, or *both*.  This is performance critical code, so I don't want to call both if I don't have to...

Comment: this is not the way to delete, and why doing so?

Comment: Yeah, you may have your reasons for wanting to dissociate with the content you have posted, but your questions and answers are still relevant - and helpful - to the community.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`_fpreset()` resets the state of the floating-point unit. It resets the FPU precision to its default **and** clears the FPU status word. The two occasitions I see to use it are when recovering from an FPE (as you said) and when getting control back from library code (e.g. a DLL that you have no control about) that has screwed the FPU in any way, like changing the precision.